# How to install uTorrent for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: server, software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and I have downloaded version 17.10. Please tell me how to get the uTorrent or is there any other way I can use to download torrents?

Comment: There's many torrent clients in the repository / software center, e.g. qBittorrent or Deluge. You can also install uTorrent in WINE, but I'd recommended trying out one of the native options first.

Comment: Are you really using a [[tag:server]], i.e. a distribution without GUI? In other words, do you need a command line torrent client?

Comment: @galoget -- the latest utorrent for linux is 5 years old. He's better off with qbittorrent

Comment: @ravery I agree with you, I was just answering to the question itself, of how to get utorrent, just in case he wants the old program.

Comment: @galoget -- however the linux version is a server, unlike the windows version which is a GUI client. Thus qbittorrent is most like the Windows uTorrent

Answer (score 3):

`qbittorrent` is in the universe repo.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then install qbittorrent:

```
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the software-center and install transmission , it`s a bittorrent manager .

Comment: [Transmission](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?transmission) is a valid answer, why the downvote?

Comment: Transmission is already included with many flavors of Ubuntu - no need to install it. See `apt rdepends transmission-gtk`

Comment: Yep thats true , weird thing that is not installed